# Read data from file if it has spaces

Tags: c, file, file-io

For example data is like this in my file now i want to scan this data and put it into a linked list then how shiuld i do? Because using fscanf will not solve the issue as i have (M tech) as a entry now if i use fscanf then it will store m in one variable and tech in another.. whereas i want m tech to be stored in one variable...

```
    \\FILE
    USERID        Firstname Latname DOB     Gender City Country Status 
    pranavagarwal208 Pranav Agarwal 20-8-1994 Male delhi india Married
    m tech
    sleeping,programming

    CSDADDY Shubhank Srivastava 9-4-1994 Male delhi india Engaged
    b-tech
    gaming,studying,programming

    pranavagarwal20 Pranav Agarwal 20-8-1994 Male delhi india Engaged
    b tech
    reading books,playing,surfing
```

Comment: The contents of any file which is getting read from any program, should be in the identical. your one line contains `b-tech` so it will picked up very well. The same way `M Tech` should be there in the file. So my suggestion is to correct the input file, instead of modifying the program.

Comment: So it looks like an empty line indicated the start of a new record. This first line is space delimited, the second line should be imported into a single string and the third line is comma separated, is that right?

Comment: Yes , empty line indicates start of a new record where in data is seperated by spaces and can be put into a LL by fscanf funvtion, 
In the second line , basically i m scanning user with his education , so there are fair chances of getting some space.
And the third line is scanning hobbies.. where in two hobbies are sperated by a comma...But still user can enter space over there as u can see in the last record. where it is reading books...

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets to read the full line in one go.